# RabbitMQ too many unwanted queues

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using celery 4.0.2 with RabbitMQ 3.6.14, configured with five queues on four servers connecting to rabbitmq-server running on one of the servers.

before a recent deploy on production server, every things just worked fine, but after that, RabbitMQ generates thousands of unwanted queue and after a few hours, RAM usage goes high (20G or higher), celery logs `miss heartbeat` from other celery servers and stop working.

Look at `/var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/<server_name>/queues` shows thousands of files and `rabbitmqctl list_queues`  shows those files:

`...
d143e25a2ffe4dbca881978d658739b1        1
6046df6f62bc422c981d416706fe4af2        1
4acc0d442fcd43a1b0ef379c370706b1        1
d24e24a680534e33a8572f38d29ea6cd        1
619f7c89b43c4400ad8bf4556ec968d6        1
ffa5a991910941d3a03b844f85880a26        1
41e66894e5c34ad5b32d3e4e6307138c        1
4dd03ac9171448759a7b964a91d7422b        1
24ff24e8fe074f5b979a9d4e4674ba08        1
16ff4b981c11422ca2d437a5fba05706        1
726271ce0ab04886acd7f59fd930dc82        1
c07a58e36fcd4623ae7c4210ef073bdf        1
....`

I never created these files (manually or in the code). Also, deleting all `mnesia/queues` files and restart RabbitMQ works, but **only** for a few hours and again the same problem.

I really appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem. Celery by default, when a task is done, generates the result of the task in a queues named after `<id_of_the_task>`. This queue will be kept for 24 hours by default and in my case, the are generated thousands of tasks in each minute and so, millions of persistent queues (for 24 hours).

So, You can put the following in `settings.py` of your django project (or in `celery.py` in your celery project according to [celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/whatsnew-3.1.html#new-rpc-result-backend)).

`CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = False`

`CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True`

`CELERY_TASK_IGNORE_RESULT = True`

`CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 60`
`